# WSO2 Api Manager userName is missing in metric data. This metric event will not be processed further

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, elk

I'm trying wso2 api manager for using it in production in future. But I cannot bind it with ELK stack correctly.

ELK is applied to wso2 through [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/on-prem/elk-installation-guide/) but when I send request to api endpoint wso2 returns me correct response from my api and also logs an error

> [2023-08-02 11:35:51,281]  WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
> [2023-08-02 11:35:53,705] ERROR - AbstractRequestDataPublisher Error occurred when publishing event.                               org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.exception.MetricReportingException: userName is missing in metric data. This metric event will not be processed further.

> at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.reporter.elk.ELKMetricEventBuilder.validate(ELKMetricEventBuilder.java:79) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?] at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.reporter.AbstractMetricEventBuilder.build(AbstractMetricEventBuilder.java:32) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?]

Hence no stats are registered

Api Manager Version: **4.2.0**

I apreciate any help cause I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: You seem to be getting an SSL error `SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown`. Have you imported all the required certificates to the client trustore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

Seems an SSL issue. Import the ELK certificate to apim client trust store (`client-truststore.jks`) in `repository/resources/security/` location and you should be able to resolve this issue